# SD Card Insertion Not Detected

Tags: rhel, udev, sd-card

I have a situation wherein my linux system (with a 2.6.32 kernel) is not detecting the insertion of an SD card after the system is booted.

It correctly detects the card when the card is inserted before the system boots.
Moreover, it can correctly detect the card if I forcibly unload and reload the sdhci and sdhci_pci kernel modules while the card is inserted.

Is there a way that I can get the system to dynamically detect card insertion so that I can provide an appropriate udev rule for automounting?

I understand that there is a way, starting in kernel 2.6.38, to instruct the kernel to poll for block devices. For a number of reasons, I need to find a solution that works with 2.6.32.

Comment: What does dmesg says?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan There is nothing reported in dmesg when the card is inserted

Comment: Does your SDcard socket have a cardDetect pin? If not, don't expect your driver to probe the bus for a card all day long! If yes, is it configured correctly? At this point, it would be good to know what kind of system we are talking about. Real hardware SDcard slots (direct MMC bus, not over USB) are typically found in embedded devices, but your tag says /rhel …